# Google keep asking for permission to authorize my online account

Tags: google, online-accounts

Seems like google accounts authorized are not persistent. Every time I reboot "online accounts" loses the permissions and I have to re-authorize Ubuntu.

Is this the default behaviour? Is there any patch/fix?[image]

Comment: It doesn't ask me everytime. Do you use application specific passwords on google?

Comment: You mean a different password for each app? No, I have a normal google account that I use to login to every product using the same password.

Comment: Just realized I haven't had my google acount enabled since I upgraded to 12.04. Just tested it an it doesn't ask me for an application specific password. Just for the normal login. I'm using google 2-step verification though I had to enter a verification code. Guess I'll have to do that again in 30 days but it doesn't ask me for my password on reboot.

Answer (score 12):

[This bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/online-accounts-account-plugins/+bug/1029289) you are facing has been fixed, but unfortunately only for Quantal. If you are on Precise, it is unlikely that the bug fix will be backported to the [Web-apps Preview PPA.](https://launchpad.net/~webapps/+archive/preview)

If you are desperate or feeling adventurous, you can download the deb file of [signon-ui](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/signon-ui) that is available in Quantal currently and install it manually.

- [How do I install a .deb file via the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/can-you-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line)

Though I must warn you I haven't tested whether the deb file actually fixes your problem. And it is very likely that it might cause other unforeseen problems, including but not limiting to breaking dependencies of other packages, not actually being functional, etc.

A relatively safer and a promising solution to fix your problem would be to upgrade to Quantal, but upgrading to a pre-release version is never a sane idea, giving the amount of development going on at the moment.

To wrap up, the bug you are facing is fixed. Either wait for Quantal to be released and upgrade your system or try out the deb file available in Quantal.

Comment: @Nick the current situation in Quantal is not all that terrible. I use 2-factor authentication for Google and it used to ask me to type out the password and the code everytime I reboot. Now, I only have to hit on the Grant access button and it relogins for me. I'll dig up a little on the bugs report against this behavior.

Comment: This is still a problem on 14.04 (at least for me)

Comment: And in 15.04, too.

Comment: This issue still persists in 14.04.3