# can't grant access to google in online accounts

Tags: google, online-accounts

when I setup my online accounts in Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit it takes me to blank page in the external browser and also displays username and password fields to fill but when I fill them out and it's time to press the button grant access it opens new tab in the external browser and the button becomes inactive and the button No thanks becomes active

Comment: Looks like it's a bug http://askubuntu.com/questions/181371/google-keep-asking-for-permission-to-authorize-my-online-account