# Ubuntu 14.04 asking Google permission

Tags: 14.04, online-accounts

This question is [related](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181371/google-keep-asking-for-permission-to-authorize-my-online-account). So every time I boot Ubuntu it keeps asking for a Google account permission and I have to go to system settings 
 and click on Grant access every time. How do I fix it?

Comment: @EliahKagan the answer said that the bug is fixed for Quantal. I am running trusty, so how come?

Comment: Unfortunately it appears this bug may still (sometimes) occur--or perhaps has been inadvertently reintroduced to--Trusty. In [the bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/account-plugins/+bug/1029289), [comment 83](https://bugs.launchpad.net/account-plugins/+bug/1029289/comments/83) reports the same or a similar problem in a 14.04 system. This might still be closed as a bug, but I've retracted my duplicate close vote. Maybe someone will have an idea (or perhaps there is some other, non-bug factor in play).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporarily enable `trusty-proposed`.

Upgrade the following packages :

```
evolution-data-server (3.10.4-0ubuntu1.2) to 3.10.4-0ubuntu1.3  
evolution-data-server-common (3.10.4-0ubuntu1.2) to 3.10.4-0ubuntu1.3  
evolution-data-server-online-accounts (3.10.4-0ubuntu1.2) to 3.10.4-0ubuntu1.3  
gir1.2-ebook-1.2 (3.10.4-0ubuntu1.2) to 3.10.4-0ubuntu1.3  
gir1.2-ebookcontacts-1.2 (3.10.4-0ubuntu1.2) to 3.10.4-0ubuntu1.3  
gir1.2-edataserver-1.2 (3.10.4-0ubuntu1.2) to 3.10.4-0ubuntu1.3  
libcamel-1.2-45 (3.10.4-0ubuntu1.2) to 3.10.4-0ubuntu1.3  
libebackend-1.2-7 (3.10.4-0ubuntu1.2) to 3.10.4-0ubuntu1.3  
libebook-1.2-14 (3.10.4-0ubuntu1.2) to 3.10.4-0ubuntu1.3  
libebook-contacts-1.2-0 (3.10.4-0ubuntu1.2) to 3.10.4-0ubuntu1.3  
libecal-1.2-16 (3.10.4-0ubuntu1.2) to 3.10.4-0ubuntu1.3  
libedata-book-1.2-20 (3.10.4-0ubuntu1.2) to 3.10.4-0ubuntu1.3  
libedata-cal-1.2-23 (3.10.4-0ubuntu1.2) to 3.10.4-0ubuntu1.3  
libedataserver-1.2-18 (3.10.4-0ubuntu1.2) to 3.10.4-0ubuntu1.3
```

After that disable `trusty-proposed` again.
Reference :

https://bugs.launchpad.net/account-plugins/+bug/1029289/comments/114

Comment: Please format the code, I can't do that, I'm on mobile :)

Comment: Great, already upvoted

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Going to the google app permission page (https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions) and deleting potentially conflicting entries (there were two for "Ubuntu") and re-doing the registration process eventually got things working again.

Answer (score 0):

If you have activated 2 step verification process, then add your google account to Ubuntu by treating it like an app. That worked for me