# Gnome Evolution constantly asks for granting Google access

Tags: gnome, evolution, google

Sometimes, when I log in, a window pops up marked "**Web authentication from Google**", saying "GNOME Evolution would like to:" followed by a list of things (view and manage mail, view email address etc.

When I enter my login details, the window disappears, then pops up again, and again, and again... Clicking on "Allow" or "Deny" makes no difference, it just keeps coming back. This seems to happen at random occasions on login, and Online Accounts seems to show everything OK.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3):

This is a known bug which happens to appear randomly for some users on different Ubuntu editions since a long time ago and here are some examples of already existing bug reports :

- [Need to authorize my Google account each time I boot the computer](https://bugs.launchpad.net/account-plugins/+bug/1029289)
- [Authorization keeps having to be re-entered](https://bugs.launchpad.net/signon-plugin-google/+bug/1033435)
- [Google account keeps losing authorization](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-online-accounts/+bug/1052577)

In many of the cases it is related to the `account-plugin-google` and the `evolution-data-server` packages which may be solved by upgrading to newer packages from the proposed repositories. Example : [Temporarily enable `trusty-proposed` - upgrade relevant packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/505753/ubuntu-14-04-asking-google-permission/527898#527898)

Unfortunately there is no guaranty that it solves the problem. As a workaround you have to either logout and back in or reboot the system, which mostly leads to correctly connecting.

You should file a new bug report on Launchpad - just as being [suggested](https://bugs.launchpad.net/account-plugins/+bug/1029289/comments/134) lately by Alberto Mardegan to a user who [informed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/account-plugins/+bug/1029289/comments/133) about the exactly same issue occuring in Ubuntu 16.10.

Comment: I finally managed to drop these notifications: https://askubuntu.com/a/1394648/162