# Can't remove Gmail calendar from previous Evolution installation

Tags: gnome, evolution, calendar, gmail

Since upgrading to 17.10 I keep getting prompted for a calendar from an old gmail account that I used to use in evolution.

I no longer use evolution or that account on this machine. Ever since I upgraded it has been asking me for the password, will not accept the correct password (not using 2-factor authentication), and there is no way for me to delete the account.

I no longer have evolution installed so I don't know where it got that account from. It is not listed in Online Accounts. I installed Evolution to see if there was a way to delete it there, and the remove button is greyed out.

Where is the configuration file that controls this so I can remove the account manually?

Comment: now that you have evolution installed, try `sudo apt-get purge evolution` to remove configuration files

Answer (score 2):

I purged Evolution and removed `~/.config/evolution/` and `~/.local/share/evolution/` and logged out and back in and the calendars were gone.

Answer (score 0):

Another config file that still contains trace of my Google Account after having deleted it from Gnome Online Account is `~/.config/goa-1.0/accounts.conf`
(cf https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/k77jp1/comment/gep8m12/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3
& https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcr/+bug/1044549/comments/14).

After I killed gnome-calendar, the constant popups from `gnome-calendar` asking about my Google password (which could never work, as the account has 2fa) seems to have stopped.