# Google asks me to login every time I reboot

Tags: password, google, online-accounts

My online account for Google loses the password every time I reboot my machine.  I have a two tier log in to my Google account as it is managed by my employer.

I am aware that this has been dealt with as a bug in previous releases and would have commented on a previous thread ([Google keep asking for permission to authorize my online account](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181371/google-keep-asking-for-permission-to-authorize-my-online-account)), but I haven't got 50 points, so am not allowed to.

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.  Has anyone figured a workaround?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a very annoying bug and seems to be an issue with the Calendar option. A fix should be in your updates soon according to the progress of this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/account-plugins/+bug/1029289). Or better yet help them verify this issue by testing the fix. Follow this [comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/account-plugins/+bug/1029289/comments/114) to [instructions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/QATeam/PerformingSRUVerification).

Comment: @Tim it looks like an answer (links to the bug and to a comment with workarounds).

Comment: Thanks for this.  Unfortunately I can't work out how to install the package.  It doesn't show up in Synaptic and I'm confused as to how I do the md5sum thing to test which package is right.  Is it the evolution-data-server_3.10.4-0ubuntu1.3.debian.tar.gz file that I need?  Once I've downloaded and extracted, how do I install it?

Perhaps I'll upgrade to 14.10 to see if that fixes it.

Comment: It's probably best to update or upgrade as this bug is marked as fixed. And since 14.10 has been released no doubt this fix should be in this release.